# In Powershell, is there a way to save a typed command into history without executing it for later execution?

Tags: command-line, powershell, history

In PowerShell, is there a way, after typing a long or complicated command, to commit that command into the history buffer, but not execute it?

For example, you start typing a git commit, within posh-git:directory:

```
git commit -m "Added the library 'ASDF' and did some initial integration into the project" [pause]
```

And right when you get that typed, I'm thinking... Uh, I need to do something first, like add an additional file to commit do something else first, or create a directory or something (contrived situation, I realize PowerShell will auto-create it and I realize git can "amend the commit".) So I'd like to save that commit message into a history buffer, but without running it, to be recalled later after I say, stage additional files or do something just before.

According to this article, [Windows PowerShell Shortcut Keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee176868(v=technet.10)), there doesn't appear to be a keystroke to do this.

<kbd>Esc</kbd> key (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) will cancel the command, and clear it out... What I need is to save to history, to be run later, thus preserving my typing.  Is there a keystroke for this?

Answer (score 12):

Well you can always put a comment tag before the command like this:

`#Get-ChildItem`

And when you are ready to execute, arrow up to the command hit <kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Del</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute.

Comment: Yep. Been using this trick for forever. I also comment my oneliners this way, because I might actually reread the history years from now (bash).

Comment: Yes this is how I currently solve the problem. I was hoping for a keyboard shortcut that would save a line into history without actually running it first.

Comment: @enorl76 Wow, the OP commented 8 years, 1 month, and 30 days later.  Is that a record?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work too, after some playing with invoke:

```
$VariableName = "Windows Command"
```

Then, to execute:

```
Invoke-Expression "$VariableName"
```

An example with Ping:

[image]

I was also able to use PowerShell expressions in the exact same way:

> PS H:> $Outlooks = "Get-Process -Name Outlook -Verbose | fl
>   StartTime, Threads" PS H:> Invoke-Expression "$Outlooks"

Essentially, I believe what is happening is that we are creating a string for the first variable (Exactly what it looks like, straight forward), and then when we invoke our variable inside " " it forces the interpreter to expand the variable, causing it to call the right command.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the command support a `-whatif` parameter that you could append and remove later.  However, I have to say I like the comment idea better.

Comment: whatif is good, but not all commands support it

Answer (score 0):

You can add the string directly to the history file like this

```
Add-Content -Value 'git commit -m "..."' -Path (Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath
```

Comment: I was hoping for a shortcut key.  I dont know what the equivalent would be in bash, but I believe theres a way to type out a command, realize you still need to get info, hit a key, save it to history, run your other command to get the info, and recall the original command from history.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but I stumbled upon while researching for a solution for the requirement.
You might take a look at my [CmdFav module at GitHUB](https://github.com/Callidus2000/CmdFav).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).