# PowerShell Expression interpreter on variables

Tags: powershell

[In response to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/606332/in-powershell-is-there-a-way-to-save-a-typed-command-into-history-without-execu/607794#607794), the original requester wanted to know

> In PowerShell, is there a way, after typing a long or complicated
>   command, to commit that command into the history buffer, but not
>   execute it?

My solution however was purely for fun, but I wondered how / why it worked on the back end.

#### Answer

```
$VariableName = "Windows Command"
```

Then, to execute:

```
Invoke-Expression "$VariableName"
```

An example with Ping:

[image]

I was also able to use PowerShell expressions in the exact same way:

> PS H:> $Outlooks = "Get-Process -Name Outlook -Verbose | fl StartTime, Threads"
>   PS H:> Invoke-Expression "$Outlooks"

#### My Theory

Essentially, I believe what is happening is that we are creating a string for the first variable (Exactly what it looks like, straight forward), and then when we invoke our variable inside " " it forces the interpreter to expand the variable, causing it to call the right command.

Is my understanding of how this works accurate? References preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that seems to be exactly what is happening (BTW you don't even need quotes around the command string while invoking).

As per the [help description](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849893.aspx) of the cmdlet (obtained via `get-help Invoke-Expression -full`):

> `iex [-Command] <String> [<CommonParameters>]`
> `Invoke-Expression [-Command] <String> [<CommonParameters>]`
>
> The Invoke-Expression cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as a command and returns the results of the expression or command. Without Invoke-Expression, a string submitted at the command line would be returned (echoed) unchanged.
>
> An expression is a statement that can be evaluated and produces a result, such as a Windows PowerShell command.

If the command stored in the string variable is not too complex you can also [use the call operator (&)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176880.aspx) as follows:

```
& $string
```

Further details courtesy [this page](http://ss64.com/ps/invoke-expression.html):

> If the result of the expression is an empty array, invoke-expression will output $null
>
> Invoke-Expression can be used to perform string expansion but if the string is supplied by an end-user you need to ensure that it does not contain malicious code/expressions.

Comment: I had tried without the quotes, and it did not work, I guess I was missing the & $String.